# How to use forked repo to create your npm package

Tags: git, github, npm

I want to use an existing git repo with some modification to my project.

I am able to fork the repo and can see it under my account.

what changes should I make to this forked repo in order to install and use it in my project just like normal package.

I am thinking these changes should be changing package name, url in package.json file. 
I have been trying find a tutorial for this but could not find any.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you solve it?

Comment: i was able to make npm package for myself. i followed the tutorial. i posted link in reply.

Comment: What about License :3?